# Change hover color on Wordpress Main menu link

Tags: php, css, wordpress, menu

I have small issue with my [main menu](https://www.kuzar.es/).

I want to update my hover color when close to menu item. Currently menu color is white on black background, but when close to menu item, it going black also, and its not visible at all. I tryed to update color in this way:

```
    .piko-layout-header .piko-navbar .piko-mega-menu.piko-mega-menu- 
    light.dark>.nav.navbar-nav>li .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
     color:#fff;
     }
```

but seems do not make any change. To explain better with image:

[image: menu problem issue]

**Thanks!!**

Comment: Use the Developer tools and locate the CSS code on the left, :hover state color #141414 !important is overriding.

Comment: Line #247 in https://www.kuzar.es/wp-content/themes/pikocon/assets/css/skin/skin-green-dark.css?ver=4.9.6 If you can change that.

Comment: Do you think on this CSS?

`.blog-comment ol li li  h4{
    color: #141414 !important;
}`

Comment: The above code is not affecting your menu.

Comment: That is line #247 from file you pointed. Or you thinked on this? `.back-top:hover{
    color: #141414 !important;`

Comment: Yeah but that's the tiny part. The code you pointed only effects the h4 tags inside blog comments. `#menu-home li a:hover` should be the code to target.

Comment: See answer on this question. That was perfect asnwer, and worked fine.

Comment: Cool. Glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I despise about so many custom built in CSS styles is the unnecessarily heavily selectors that overwrite each other.

Here's the current CSS  that's styling it black:

```
/*... */
.piko-layout-header .piko-navbar .piko-mega-menu > .nav.navbar-nav > li > .piko-link:hover,
/*...*/ {
    color: #141414 !important
}
```

Blech. You can confirm this by opening dev tools and adding the `:hover` pseudo class to the link.

Stick this in your CSS after the `skin-green-dark` file or in the Appearance > Customizer > Additional CSS:

```
.piko-layout-header .piko-navbar .piko-mega-menu > .nav.navbar-nav > li > .piko-link:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

If that's still being overwritten it means it's been overwritten with that selector above, and you can make yours a bit heavier with more specificity by changing it to:

```
header.piko-layout-header .piko-navbar .piko-mega-menu > .nav.navbar-nav > li > .piko-link:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

These hyper specific selectors become such a hassle especially when they start throwing `!important` around that they become incredibly tedious to overwrite.